# Cómo le digo al plugin select2 qué elemento poner, llenado por Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, select2

Queria saber como le digo al plugin que elemnto poner y que no me arroje el select vacio:

```
var id_proveedor = data[0]['id_proveedor'];  //id del proveedor sacado de del Json
var proveedor = data[0]['nombre_proveedor']; //nombre del proveedor sacado de del Json
```

Esta en la funcion donde cargo dinamicamente mi `.select2` :

```
function  combo_select2() {
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = $.noop;
    $("#nombre_proveedor").select2({
//        destroy: true,
        theme: "bootstrap",
        placeholder: "Buscar proveedor",
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: {
            url: baseurl + 'Compras/obtener_proveedor',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (obj) {
                        return {
                            id: obj.id_proveedor,
                            text: obj.nombre_proveedor
                        };
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
}
```

Esta es la funcion donde cargo los datos de una compra con los datos previamente listados de la BD:

```
    function modificar_compra(id_compra) {
            combo_select2();
            $.ajax({
                url: baseurl + 'Compras/obtener_compra',
                type: "POST",
                data: {id_compra: id_compra},
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $("#modal_form_compra").unbind();
                    $('#modal_form_compra').modal('show')
                    $("#div_imagen_subir").hide();
                    $("#div_imagen").show();
                    $('#boton_multiuso').attr("onclick", 'actualizar_compra(' + id_compra + ')');
                    $('#eliminar_imagen').attr("onclick", 'borrar_imagen(' + id_compra + ')');
                    $('#msg_cabecera').html("EDITAR COMPRA #" + id_compra);
                    $('#numero_compra').val(data[0]['numero_recibo']);
                    $('#id_proveedor').val(data[0]['id_proveedor']);
                    $('#monto_total').val(data[0]['monto_total']);
                    $('#fecha_compra').val(data[0]['fecha']);
                    var id_proveedor = data[0]['id_proveedor'];  //id del proveedor sacado de del Json
                    var proveedor = data[0]['nombre_proveedor']; //nombre del proveedor sacado de del Json
                    console.log(proveedor);
        //            $("#nombre_proveedor").val(id_proveedor);
        //            $("#nombre_proveedor").val("{SERVICIO MORE S.A.C.}");
        //            $("#nombre_proveedor").select2("val", "SERVICIO MORE S.A.C.");
        //            $('#nombre_proveedor').val("hola").trigger('change.select2');
        //            $('#nombre_proveedor').select2('data', {nombre_proveedor: proveedor, id_proveedor: '1234'})
        //            $("#nombre_proveedor").select2().val(proveedor).trigger("change")
        //            $('#nombre_proveedor').val(proveedor).trigger('change');
        //            $('#nombre_proveedor').val("SERVICIO MORE S.A.C.").trigger('change.select2');
                    $('#id_imagen_editar').attr("src", baseurl + 'dist/img/compras/' + data[0]['url_imagen']);
                }
            });
        }
```

MI HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-6">Proveedor</label>
         <input id="id_proveedor" type="hidden">
           <div class="col-md-12">
             <select class="form-control select2" id="nombre_proveedor"
              style="width: 100%"></select> <span class="help-block"></span>
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Como pueden ver e intendo varios metodos sin ningun resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el success donde obtienes el resultado de la compra deberías establecer el valor del select, algo como

```
$("#nombre_proveedor").val(id_proveedor);
```

Como el select se carga con ajax podrias crear un option manualmente y despues hacer el val anteriormente comentado

```
$('#nombre_proveedor').append($('<option>', {
  value: id_proveedor,
  text: proveedor
 }));
```

algo asi

```
 function modificar_compra(id_compra) {
        combo_select2();
        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + 'Compras/obtener_compra',
            type: "POST",
            data: {id_compra: id_compra},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data)
            {
                $("#modal_form_compra").unbind();
                $('#modal_form_compra').modal('show')
                $("#div_imagen_subir").hide();
                $("#div_imagen").show();
                $('#boton_multiuso').attr("onclick", 'actualizar_compra(' + id_compra + ')');
                $('#eliminar_imagen').attr("onclick", 'borrar_imagen(' + id_compra + ')');
                $('#msg_cabecera').html("EDITAR COMPRA #" + id_compra);
                $('#numero_compra').val(data[0]['numero_recibo']);
                $('#id_proveedor').val(data[0]['id_proveedor']);
                $('#monto_total').val(data[0]['monto_total']);
                $('#fecha_compra').val(data[0]['fecha']);
                var id_proveedor = data[0]['id_proveedor'];  //id del proveedor sacado de del Json
                var proveedor = data[0]['nombre_proveedor']; //nombre del proveedor sacado de del Json
                console.log(proveedor);
    //            $("#nombre_proveedor").val(id_proveedor);
    //            $("#nombre_proveedor").val("{SERVICIO MORE S.A.C.}");
    //            $("#nombre_proveedor").select2("val", "SERVICIO MORE S.A.C.");
    //            $('#nombre_proveedor').val("hola").trigger('change.select2');
    //            $('#nombre_proveedor').select2('data', {nombre_proveedor: proveedor, id_proveedor: '1234'})
    //            $("#nombre_proveedor").select2().val(proveedor).trigger("change")
    //            $('#nombre_proveedor').val(proveedor).trigger('change');
    //            $('#nombre_proveedor').val("SERVICIO MORE S.A.C.").trigger('change.select2');
                  $('#nombre_proveedor').append($('<option>', {
  value: id_proveedor,
  text: proveedor
 }));

                $("#nombre_proveedor").val(id_proveedor);
                $('#id_imagen_editar').attr("src", baseurl + 'dist/img/compras/' + data[0]['url_imagen']);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: nada hermano, ya nose que hacer :c

Comment: Me parece que como se carga en ajax al vuelo al momento de establecer el valor el select no tiene ningún elemento entonces podrias crear un option para se vea como seleccionado o invokar a tu ajax y entonces hacer el .val

Comment: Suena tonto pero en que parte lo pongo :c, puedes poner el codigo completo porfa

Comment: prueba esto  $("#nombre_proveedor").val(id_proveedor).trigger("change")

Comment: @JackNavaRow suena bien así te ahorras el crear el option aun que creandolo manual te ahorras el post, pero me agrada mas el trigger change

Comment: @JackNavaRow ese metodo ya lo probe, incluso esta en mi codigo, Carlos Cocom una ultima pregunta :C salio todo perfecto pero siempre cuando entro a ese modulo y le doy en editar a cualquiera no carga salgo y le doy otra vez ahi si me carga? que estara pasando?

Comment: $("#nombre_proveedor").val({nombre_proveedor: proveedor, id_proveedor: '1234'}).trigger("change"); claro por que tienes que manejar el objeto completo

Comment: @JackNavaRow ese tambien probe fijate en mi codigo

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores no veo el ejemplo que me pasaste; lo mas cercano es esto $("#nombre_proveedor").select2().val({nombre_proveedor: proveedor, id_proveedor: '1234'}).trigger("change"), fijate que quite el select2()

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores el metodo que tienes iniciado tu rutina "combo_select2();" deberia estar en la inicializacion de la pagina no cada vez que utilizas la rutina ademas tienes el cache = true y si solo hay un option puede ser por ahi como se con la inicializacion correcta deberia funcionar ademas antes de agregar el option deberias ver si no existe

Comment: @CarlosCocom ya me enrrede, una docuemntacion o ejemplo por ahi?

Answer (score 2):

buscando la solución a un problema similar y leyendo las repuesta de muchos de uds logré dar con la siguiente solución:
primero agrego el valor al combo (ya que el mismo se carga vía ajax en otro momento). Luego se selecciona y si se despliega el combo se puede observar seleccionado. Espero ayude.

```
var $example = $("#idGroup").select2();
$example.append($('<option>', { //agrego los valores que obtengo de una base de datos
                        value: '2',
                        text: 'Admins'
                       }));
$example.val('2').trigger("change"); //lo selecciona
```

Answer (score 2):

He probado [el código de Alejandro Landini](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/97727/127), el cual funciona muy bien pero solo cuando se carga un elemento.Si son múltiples opciones, no funciona.

La forma correcta sería agregar **`selected: true`**.

El ejemplo seria el siguiente:

```
var $example = $("#idGroup").select2();
$example.append($('<option>', { //agrego los valores que obtengo de una base de datos
    value: '2',
    text: 'Admins',
    selected: true
}));
```

Nota: Esto debe estar dentro de un for o foreach que recorra el objeto obtenido de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

La variable **datos** es el `json`

```
myArray = [];// Inicializo un array
```

Recorro el objeto `json`

```
$.each(datos, function(i, item) {
  myArray.push(item.campoid);
});

console.log(myArray);
$('#elselect').val( myArray ).trigger('change');
```

Funciona para **select multiples**

Comment: Hola EdwinB, no termina de quedar clara tu respuesta. ¿Podrías editarla para añadir una descripción de lo que hace y cómo funciona? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).